# How to disable/enable a slider which uses selectToUiSlider jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, jquery-ui-slider

I am using a jQuery plugin to create sliders with ticks, labels and tooltips. I am in need of a way to be able to disable/enable it like a textbox or combobox. For e.g. When user land on the page the slider appears disabled but when user changes a dropbox or slide another slider this should get enabled. I couldn't find any documentation on this particular functionality. Need help.

```
//SLIDER 1
$('select#milestones').selectToUISlider({
    labels:4,
    tooltip: false,
    labelSrc: 'text',
    sliderOptions:{
        change: function(e, ui) {
            filterAndLoadChart((parseInt(ui.value)) + 1);
            if(ui.value > 0){
                //I WANT TO ENABLE THE SLIDER 2 HERE
            }
        }
    }
});

//SLIDER 2
$('select#age').selectToUISlider({
    tooltip: false,
    labelSrc: 'value',
    sliderOptions:{
        disabled:true,
        change:function(e, ui) {
            var selVal = $('#age').val();
            $("#ageTxt").html(selVal + " Days");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

selectToUISlider create slider with class ui-slider
so you can disable/enable it with standart jquery-ui slider method:

`$('.ui-slider').slider('disable');`

`$('.ui-slider').slider('enable');`